# Pure JSON database

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a ReactJS application which is a personal/news site (half of both). It has a publications section which requires a database to list and store all of the entries. The only user that will be able to edit/add/delete publications is the admin. Also, the format of every publication will be the same. So a separate backend application would be like inventing a bicycle. Too complex for a simple thing like publications.

The first thing i tried to use is the Firebase from google. (https://firebase.google.com/). It is really simple, has real-time synchronization (which is useless in my case) and also does all the dirty job for you. That is really awesome, but i got a problem. The website contains many high-resolution images and many of them have to be loaded at the same time. I realised, that the website takes about 2-3 seconds to load and that's with only a couple of images.

Than i thought about a local storage on the same host. I did a few test with local storage and, of course, it's many times faster (3s vs milliseconds). So now i think about a JSON file which will contain all the information (Image paths, paragraph text, names e.t.c).

1 - will it be safe to store everything on the same host with such an easy to access DB? It's okay if users can read the files cause they will be available on the website anyway. But is there a possibility that they also will be able to change them?

2 - to manipulate the DB i think about making a simple app-interface which will allow to edit the publications visually. But will it be safe (x2) to store that interface on the same host? Of course it won't be running on a public IP and will be stored in another directory.

Comment: Your speed test is likely very flawed by browser caching. Where you store the paths to images is irrelevant to how long they take to load. Big file = long load. If browser already has the file in cache image loads much much faster

Comment: Whatever the loading time from the computer is, it will sum with the downloading time from firebase, isn't it?

Comment: Presumaby you have paths stored in firebase database and images in their storage.Getting the database data takes next to no time...it's the actual image loading that takes time based on each file size

Comment: If i test the speed after restarting the browser, will the cache clean up?

Comment: need to either turn of caching or delete the cache